# Splitting chunk of data in Firestore document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

What is the best approach to handle small chunk of data on Firestore while keeping the read and write operations minimum.

We are working on a small problem statement where we want to offer users ability to rate/review any store they see on the application.

The approach I see is to create a document of store with some set of attributes of store (store name, store address, aggregated rating) and then create a sub-collection of rating/review with each user rating as a document.

```
/stores/{storeid}/rating/{rating_from_each_user}
```

But this will result in a lot of read operations, every-time someone tries to read a review from store. Also we can't keep all ratings in 1 document due to 1MB limitation eventually the number of ratings will grow and this won't scale.

Please do share if you have any other approaches in mind for best practice.

Comment: Use Firebase database because there is no problem regarding the number of reads.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AlexMamo . But I am bit skeptical about the future of Firebase Realtime Database, as Firebase team is constantly suggesting to use Firestore for all new projects.

Also, keeping the data on two instances will result in difficulty if we plan for migration later.

Do you have any other ideas with respect to Firestore implementation on this?

Comment: @KumarVivek I am on the Firebase team, I think you have the wrong impression.  If you like the Realtime Database you should absolutely continue to use it / build new apps on it.  It's not going anywhere and Cloud Firestore is not a replacement, just another option.

Comment: @hatboysam thanks for the confirmation, that is a relief.

I would definitely go for Realtime database if this can't be resolved in firestore.

Do you have any suggestions on implementation of the problem I discussed above in firestore?

Comment: I think you're right in that this system in Cloud Firestore will require many document reads to load all of the ratings for a page.  However I think you need to do some napkin calculations to see if that's actually a problem for your app/budget.  RTDB charges much more for cold/storage and for bandwidth so it's not as if these queries are free on either system.

Comment: Thanks @hatboyman for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, i recomand you using `Firebase Realtime Database`. As mentioned in this [post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/10/cloud-firestore-for-rtdb-developers.html) from the Firebase offical blog, one the reasons you still might want to use the Realtime Database is:

> As we noted above, Cloud Firestore's pricing model means that applications that perform very large numbers of small reads and writes per second per client could be significantly more expensive than a similarly performing app in the Realtime Database.

So, you know your budget. In this case is up to you which option you choose.

Hope it helps.